# Как прекратить ожидание ответа от requests запроса после его отправки на сервер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Я знаю про параметр timeout в теле запроса requests, но мне необходимо прекратить ожидание ответа в произвольный момент времени. Существует ли команда или способ прекратить ожидание ответа?

Comment: Нет. Код отправки выполняется синхронно. Но можно попробовать поместить его в поток/процесс и прибить их

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо, так и сделаю!

Comment: Что значит "отменить запрос"? Как Вы себе это представляете на сетевом уровне?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов прервать именно со стороны клиента. Например можно отправить запрос в консоли и отменить его через нажатие Ctrl+C. И как работает timeout прерывая запрос через заданное время?

Comment: Вы совершенно не понимаете, как работает сеть. То, о чём Вы говорите, это не отмена запроса, а **прекращение ожидания** ответа. Запрос улетает практически моментально. `timeout` - время ожидания ответа, если в течение этого времени ответ от сервера не пришел, то считаем запрос неуспешным.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Тогда сформулирую вопрос так: Как прекратить ожидание ответа после отправки запроса на сервер без использования timeout? И что можете посоветовать почитать, чтобы разораться как работает сеть.

Comment: @leach Лучше сам вопрос редактируйте. По сетям что-то конкретное посоветовать не могу, могу только сказать, что я изучал по курсу "Сети для самых маленьких" на хабре и по лекциям Андрея Созыкина на YouTube.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Вопрос отредактировал, спасибо за советы.

Comment: я бы перешел на асинхроные запросы